# How to Query between string dates in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I have the following under mycolumn in an Oracle DB

1996-02-14-02.28.37.404000

1996-02-14-02.28.37.404001

1996-02-14-02.28.37.418000

1996-02-16-02.53.00.248000

1996-02-16-02.53.00.265000

How can I select some values using **WHERE** in Oracle SQL?

I tried the following

```
SELECT TO_DATE(mycolumn, '%Y-%m-%d-%H.%i.%s.%f') 
  FROM mytable 
 WHERE TO_DATE(mycolumn, '%Y-%m-%d-%H.%i.%s.%f') > timestamp '2013-02-14 02:28:37.404' 
   AND TO_DATE(mycolumn, '%Y-%m-%d-%H.%i.%s.%f') < timestamp '2013-03-14 02:28:37.404';
```

Comment: not like that.  Why are you storing dates as strings?  That is really bad practice.  It should be a DATE or TIMESTAMP data type. See here https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `mycolumn` column's datatype is `timestamp` (should be; I hope you aren't storing those values into a `varchar2` column), then you'd e.g.

```
select *
from mytable
where mycolumn > to_timestamp('2013-02-14 02:28:37.404', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff3');
```

In other words, don't touch `mycolumn` and provide valid format model for value you're comparing it with.

---

If it really is a string (in a `varchar2` column), then do the same for both values, e.g.

```
where to_timestamp(mycolumn, 'yyyy-mm-dd-hh24.mi.ss.ff6') > 
      to_timestamp('2013-02-14 02:28:37.404', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff3')
```

Comment: the data is already stored as char (26) in column "mycolumn"

Comment: The solution for the varchar2 column worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome. If possible, fix that - there's no guarantee that someone won't store e.g. 'ABCD-13-24-ac#4x&dd.12fd#r' into that column and all your queries will fail. Also, next time, choose data datatype wisely. Good luck!